# Can I export two objects from one Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

I'm wondering if I can export two objects from a Vue.js component such that other components can choose which one to use.

Here's the example I'm working with:

AboutFooBar.vue:

```
<template>
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Foo',
    data: () => {
      return {
        text: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }
  const Bar = {
    name: 'Bar',
    data: () => {
      return {
        text: 'bar'
      }
    }
  }
  export { Bar }
</script>
```

Then I import both Foo and Bar in About.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is the about page</h1>
    <Foo /><br/>
    <Bar />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Foo from './AboutFooBar'
  import { Bar } from './AboutFooBar'

  export default {
    name: 'About',
    components: {
      Foo,
      Bar
    },
    data: () => {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I'm expecting to see on the page is:

```
This is the about page
Foo
Bar
```

...but instead I see:

```
This is the about page
Foo
```

So it seems like it doesn't recognize Bar. I was expecting that I could setup a choice of which object to import, and the data of that object would determine what gets filled into the template (so the text 'foo' for component Foo and 'bar' for component Bar).

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: If aboutfoobar has a prop why don't you just send a different prop for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think this is almost certainly not a good pattern.  Components should be properly reduced and encapsulated, and readable.

If, like the example, `Foo` and `Bar` were similar, they should be one component, called twice, and given different props each time.  On the other hand, if they are different, they should be different components.

Still, for the sake of answering the question:  [Vue loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/) expects and requires the default export to contain the component.  This is the reason for the behavior you noticed.

Others have asked about this and Evan You (creator of Vue) [has commented in this feature request](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1234).  I'll include his comments here too:

> The component itself must be the default export. That's a requirement.
>
> Features like hot module replacement, CSS injection, scoped CSS, SSR critical CSS collection all depend on being able to precisely locate the exported component - it will not work if the component can be exported as an arbitrarily named component. In addition, there are tools (ESLint plugin, for example) that are based on the assumption of the component being the default export.
>
> TL;DR: the component must be the default export and this is not going to change.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree about the props thing. I'm just experimenting with export, trying to figure out how it works in vue.js. This answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

One way dividing AboutFooBar.vue to AboutFoo.vue and AboutBar.vue. But it is no useful, because they are almost same. so would you like to use props?

child.vue:

```
<template>
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Child',
    props: {
      msg: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    data: () => {
      return {
        text: this.msg
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

About.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is the about page</h1>
    <Child :msg="Foo" /><br/>
    <Child :msg="Bar" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child'

  export default {
    name: 'About',
    components: {
      Child
    }
  }
</script>
```